# what does it mean "Non-responsive usage of Bootstrap"?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap 4 [change log](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/) I see

> Non-responsive usage of Bootstrap is no longer supported.

What should that mean? How do I know when some usage is (non-)responsive?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/

Comment: I also voted to close as this is a too broad question

Comment: The just probably changed the functionality of "container" so it works like "container-fluid" and removed "container-fluid"

Comment: @LGSon, I wonder why do you think it is broad. I think that I pointed exactly what I am asking about and answers are great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the responsive in Bootstrap 3 by the following steps,

and this is the *non-responsive usage* you mentioned.
<kbd>[Source](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.2/docs/getting-started/#community)</kbd>:

1. Omit the viewport `<meta>` mentioned in the CSS docs
2. Override the `width` on the `.container` for each grid tier with a single width, for example `width: 970px !important;` Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the `!important` with media queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use `.col-xs-*` classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

[Here's the official example](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.2/docs/examples/non-responsive/).

In Bootstrap 4, these might break the styles since the *Non-responsive usage* is no longer supported.

Comment: The question was not how to do it in Bootstrap 3, it was what it means, and how does this answer that?

Comment: He's asking for "How do I know when some usage is (non-)responsive", so I just show him what is "(non-)responsive".

Answer (score 1):

You can disable responsiveness of bootstrap by removing the following meta tag from website page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Here is the link : [Disabling responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

Comment: Yes but that guy is talking about Bootstrap 4, not 3. For example, I'm working on the admin dashboard, where responsiveness us useless for me, as I need to view 12columns in one table.